# SharePoint Online - How to create link for calendar list item .ics file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, calendar, sharepoint-calendar, events

I am developing link for calendar list item .ics file. 
Link for 'Add to my calendar' on SharePoint Online inside SPFX webpart

I have tried below URL but it's not working:

```
<a href="http://<SITE_URL>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List={<LIST_GUID>}&CacheControl=1&ID=<ITEM_ID>&Using=event.ics"> Add to my calendar <a>
```

Please help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List GUID should be added without `{ }`:

```
<a href="http://<SITE_URL>/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=<LIST_GUID>&CacheControl=1&ID=<ITEM_ID>&Using=event.ics"> Add to my calendar <a>
```

The link should be like this:

```
https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?CS=109&Cmd=Display&List=A70BA8FB-6F03-4545-81EF-7E30D893FBC1&CacheControl=1&ID=1&Using=event.ics
```

Comment: This is not working as expected.